# UnicodeDecodeError in Flask app calling pysphere

Tags: python, flask

I'm completely new to Flask. I have some code that will copy a file over to a virtual machine using the pysphere library. This works fine on its own, but when I try using a Flask app, I get:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

At first I figured it is just because the web form is passing something it doesn't like. However, I decided to hard code the values and it still fails. Here is the code:

```
@app.route('/begin_install', methods=['POST'])
def begin_install():
    source_installer_path = app.root_path + '/installers'
    installer_file = str(request.form['installer'])
    option_file_path = app.root_path + '/installers/options'
    option_file = 'testing.options'

    vmserver.start_install( request.form['vm'],
                        source_installer_path,
                        installer_file,
                        option_file_path,
                        option_file)

    return render_template('results.html')
```

Then, in my pysphere related file:

```
def start_install(self, vmpath, installer_path, installer_file, options_path, options_file):
    vm.revert_to_named_snapshot('python_install')
    vm.power_on()
    while vm.get_tools_status() != 'RUNNING':
        sleep(3)
    vm.login_in_guest(self.guest_user, self.guest_password)
    vm.send_file('C:\\folder\\filetosend.exe', 'c:\\installer\\filename.exe')
```

Everything up to the "vm.send_file" works perfectly fine. If I call the same code from a non-Flask app, it also works perfectly fine. I'm very confused about why I'm getting errors from Flask when this part of the code is all pysphere.

EDIT: Here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\username\Flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Users\username\Flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\username\Flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\username\Flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\username\Flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\python\PycharmProjects\installtest\installtest.py", line 51, in begin_install
    option_file)
  File "C:\python\PycharmProjects\installtest\testmachines.py", line 56, in start_install
    'c:\\installer\\filename.exe')
  File "C:\Users\username\Flask\lib\site-packages\pysphere\vi_virtual_machine.py", line 1282, in send_file
    resp = opener.open(request)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 1174, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 958, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 992, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 812, in _send_output
    msg += message_body
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: \x90 is part of the latin-1 charset ... not sure where the \x90 is coming from but its a capital E with an accent over it

Comment: You are passing a bytestring to something that expects unicode, but you didn't include the full traceback for us to help analyze *where* that goes wrong. Could you update your post with that?

Comment: I have added the traceback. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Can you run this in a debugger? In the last list, one of msg and message_body is unicode while the other is str. All input from Flask is unicode so that's likely to be reason.

Comment: I used the debugger at set a breakpoint up in the "httplib.py" line 958 and stepped until I found the issue. It turns out it doesn't like the binary data from the file I am sending. That is probably where it was picking up the \x90. I guess I don't understand why it is even going through httplib.py when I am calling pysphere.

Comment: It's calling httplib because that's how pysphere is implemented, using HTTP calls to the vsphere server. Compare sys.getdefaultencoding() on your flask app vs. however you were running where this code is working. That may give you some info about what's causing it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the traceback `pysphere` uses `urllib2` which is in turn using `httplib`.

As far as I know, httplib is concatenating the whole http request without further checking for unicode strings. And python returns always unicode if one part is unicode.

I think your *pysphere gets somehow poluted* with unicodes either in the `request` or the `opener` in the `send_file` method:

```
  File "C:\Users\username\Flask\lib\site-packages\pysphere\vi_virtual_machine.py", line 1282, in send_file
    resp = opener.open(request)
```

you should check how you are creating resp. configuring your `vm` instance and probably in detail which header is unicode and how is that affecting the `request` or the `opener` instantiation.